# kivy: How do I update an objects property?

Tags: python, oop, kivy, kivy-language

I got a python script and a kivy file to build the interface.

I want to update the Text inside a label dynamically through pythons input (network input).

So I created a property for the main kivy widget:

```
class UserForm(BoxLayout):
    txt = StringProperty("")
```

inside of kivy I use `on_txt` to call some changes inside of the widgets below:

```
<UserForm>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    name: name_input.text
    barcode: barcode_input.text
    on_txt: print ("Aha"); barcode_label.text = "I CHANGED FOR THE BETTER"
    Label:
        id: barcode_label
        text: "barcode (EAN or SN):"
        font_size: 30
```

It prints "Aha" and throws no errors but it also does not change the text of the label.

Appreciate any help or hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do this in python

```
class UserForm(Screen):
  on_enter(self):
    self.barcode_label.text='I CHANGED FOR THE BETTER'
```

this will change the code to this every time you enter the screen
Alternative
if you want something else try this

```
class UserForm(Screen):
    def changetext(self):
        self.barcode_label.text='I CHANGED FOR THE BETTER'
```

and in ur kv file do this

```
<UserForm>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    name: name_input.text
    barcode: barcode_input.text
    barcode_label:barcode_label
    Label:
        id: barcode_label
        text: "barcode (EAN or SN):"
        font_size: 30
    Button:
        text: 'press me'
        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.3}
        size_hint:(0.1,0.1)
        on_press:root.changetext()
```

this gives u a button to press to change the text
let me know if you get any errors

Comment: thx! the 2nd one was what i was looking for.
the 1st seems even more attractive but quick test did not have the effect I wished for (stayed on kivy language defined text).

Comment: but follow up: how would I call the changetext() method from python and still get the same update? e.g. when i have another thread running with a server waiting for network signals or if python processes inputs before passing them back into the kivy widgets...

Comment: i dont think you can call this function outside this class. But explain exactly what you want to happen, ill try my best to help you, if you want to refresh the screen i can help you with that or something? can u please explain your program abit more so i get an understanding of what you need doing

Comment: thank you so much! 
i guess u are right: my problem lies in updating the screen regularly.

my program does the following:
1) python opens an OSC-server and listens for inputs on a port

2) it builds with kivy an user interface where the user can type in some data that gets send out over the network (works so far)

3) when data from another computer arrives on the network port the script i am listening for (outside of the main kivy loop that would be), i want the event listener for the network input to pass the incoming data into kivy in order to display it there.